# Place div on top of specific part of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I was wondering, is it possible to place a div on top of a specific part of an image without the div moving when the window size changes?

Example: Placing an image inside of the "PLACE IMAGE HERE", and the image should stay inside of that area when resizing the screen:

[image]

I tried to use `position: absolute` but obviously that doesn't work when the window size changes.

Comment: Using percentages for the absolute positioning usually works quite well for stuff like this.

Comment: Good advice by @Cbroe. I've also had good experiences with usage of position: absolute / fixed and % values to place the element.

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked perfectly :) I also gave the image a height and width of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define both width and height for both image - the outer one and the screen one. Or you can give relative width and height in %, vh, vw or some other relative values in css. But again, it will crop the image in some device, you need to be careful while giving proper sizes using media queries also.